# Rails select not working on edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

For my `@line` model I have a form that works perfectly when included as a partial on my NEW line page but raises `undefined method`empty?' for nil:NilClass` when included on my EDIT page.

The Edit page has:

```
<%= form_for(@line, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal"} ) do |f| %>
            <%= render 'form', f: f %>
         <%= f.submit "Submit changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The form looks like this (minus divs):

```
<%= f.label :name, class: "control-label" %>
<%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'A relatively short line name' %>

<%= f.label :description, class: "control-label" %>

<%= f.text_area :description, placeholder: 'Full line name and any description' %>

<%= f.label :manufacturer_id, class: "control-label" %>

<%= f.select :manufacturer_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Manufacturer.all, :id, :name, {:selected => @line.manufacturer}) %>

<%= f.label :parent_id, class: "control-label" %>

<%= f.select :parent_id, @lines, {:selected => @line.parent, include_blank: true} %>
```

The problem is with the select options on the last list. I'm using `@lines` to populate the dropdown with all existing lines. I'll probably change that to use AJAX to populate it with only the lines that belong to the manufacturer selected above but for now I just want to get the edit function working.

I'm sure it's an obvious mistake but no amount of looking on here and reading the documentation has found a solution so far.

If it's useful, here is my controller actions:

```
def edit
    @line = Line.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @line = Line.find(params[:id])
    if @line.update_attributes(line_params)
      flash[:success] = "Line updated. #{undo_link}"
      redirect_to @line
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the above answers and getting stuck on how to get the line names showing in the dropdown properly, I've got it working with the following:

```
<%= f.select :parent_id, ("<option></option>" + options_from_collection_for_select(Line.all, :id, :name, {:selected => @line.parent_id})).html_safe %>
```

Got everything working and didn't need any alterations to controller.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't defining `@lines` anywhere in your `edit` action, so when you use it as an argument in your view, it is returning `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your edit action, because you aren't defining `@lines` anywhere:

```
def edit
    @line = Line.find(params[:id])
    @likes = Like.all
end
```

or you can call your index action as:

```
def edit
    @line = Line.find(params[:id])
    index
end
```

or you can change your form:

```
= f.select :user_id, Company.all, {:selected => @company.name, include_blank: true}
```

I think it will help you.